# symfony 4 - InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

Hi I'm trying to add symfony unit test for a form. This is my code...

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/user/new');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form(array(
            'user[displayName]' => 'user',
            'user[username]' => 'user@yahoo.com',
            'user[password]' => 'user123',
            'user[phoneNumber]' => '1234789',
            'user[roles]' => 'ROLE_USER',
        ));
        $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

        $this->assertGreaterThan(
                0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Le tue modifiche sono state salvate!")')->count()
        );
```

But I only ends up with this error,

> InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty.

It works when **I try with language English** but only fail when I change my default language to Italian in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be I need italian translation for the button. **The current node list is empty** meant can't get  `$form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')` node. since I have translated the interface to italy It had to be changed to italian wording.

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Salva')
```

And You can get by class or id so language will not matter.

```
$form = $crawler->filter('button.btn-success')
```

I'm keeping this in case anyone may lean something from it...